# Jupyter Scheduler UI is not working on Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, pypi, jupyter-extensions

I have install jupyter_scheduler extension successfully but the Notebook Jobs UI tab doesn't show anything. Is there something I've been doing wrong?(I'm working on JupyterLab 4.0.8 on Macbook)

[the discription image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LMNu.png)

I tried reinstalled and reloaded and everything, but it doesn't show as expected in the document https://jupyter-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/index.html

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try reporting an issue on https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter-scheduler/issues ?